# Merge roles in vertica

Tags: vertica

Do you know if there is a smart way to merge different roles into one single role in HP vertica database?
I mean, I have 3 roles with different grants in vertica, and I need to merge those 3 into 1.
Is there a smart way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this?

```
SQL>create role one;
role created
SQL>create role two;
role created
SQL>create role three;
role created
SQL>create role allofthem;
role created
SQL>grant one,two,three to allofthem; 
grant  succeeded
```

cheers ...

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a quick solution, create a new role and grant that role each of the three roles you are wanting to merge, but other than that, no there is no functionality to merge the three into one.

In the past I have queried the `grants` table and done string concatenation to produce grant statements. Something like:

```
SELECT 'GRANT ' || priveleges_description || ' ON TABLE ' || object_schema || '.' || object_name || ' TO merged_role;'
FROM grants
WHERE
    grantee IN ('role1', 'role2', 'role3')
    WHERE object_type = 'TABLE'
;
```

This query is NOT comprehensive. You will need to modify it to work with tables and schemas, etc. You will also need to account for the `WITH GRANT OPTION` clause, but you get the basic idea.